# OBS Studio MacOS "Failed to create directory ../config/obs-studio/basic" when launched in portable mode

Tags: obs, obs-studio

The issue occurs when launching OBS Studio in Portable mode on MacOS.

I couldn't find a complete resource on how to launch OBS in portable mode on MacOS, however after researching through forums I was able to launch OBS from the terminal with the following line:

```
/Applications/OBS.app/Contents/MacOS/obs --studio-mode
```

However when I try to add the '-p' parameter as described [here](https://obsproject.com/wiki/Launch-Parameters):

```
/Applications/OBS.app/Contents/MacOS/obs -p --studio-mode
```

I get prompted with an error window containing this error:

> Failed to create directory ../config/obs-studio/basic

Answer (score -1):

After many attempts I found the solution being that OBS doesn't have permission to create the necessary directories in order to run in portable mode.

Every tutorial on Windows, explain how it's necessary to run the app as Admin.
And this post on the OBS Forum briefly cites how they ran into the same issue and solved it with 'sudo', but doesn't properly explain how.

I therefore changed the command like this:

```
   sudo /Applications/OBS.app/Contents/MacOS/obs -p --studio-mode
```